# I cannot position the border line correctly

Tags: html, css, web, sass, border

I cannot position the borderline correctly in mobile view. Any recommendations?
[image]

This is the borderline. (Pic 1)

[image]
Desired output (Pic 2)

[image]
My output (pic 3)

This is my code

```
&__lines {
    &::before {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      background-image: url('/img/title_lines.png');
      width: 1220px;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: 8px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      @include sp {
        background-image: url('/img/title_lines.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 10 0% 7px;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. We have set a pattern image as a background in `.line` element and make `h2` as **inline-block**, so we don't need to add pseudo-element.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/718ybLan/6/

```
.lines{
  position:relative;
  background: url("https://ucarecdn.com/73760f64-cf10-4e79-8471-bd095f9dc0b6/slash.png") repeat-x center center / auto 10px;
  text-align: center;
  h2{
    font-size:32px;
    line-height:42px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    background-color:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add text into the span tag and give background color and padding to the span

```
<h2 class="lines"><span>New Arrivals</span></h2>
.lines span{
        background: #fff;
        padding: 0 10px;
}
```